# Android GUI Generator IDE

Tags: android

is there any IDE that I can drag and drop user interface for android and generate the xml for  different screen size? I'm using netbeans anhd I'm aware of eclipse but it is not good as well - eg cannot preview for different screen size etc. DroidDraw is not accurate. I'm willing to pay for thr IDE

Comment: What do you mean by "but the GUI is not good as well"?

Comment: I mean the generated and preview ability is no good

Comment: "eg cannot preview for different screen size etc" -- yes, it can. It has had that ability for over a year now. This post describes what is there today and what is coming up in the upcoming R20 tools release: http://tools.android.com/recent/newconfigchooser

Comment: yeah, you can do this with the eclipse plugin.  Click `Graphical Layout` at the bottom of the editor when you have an xml view open.  The dropdowns at the very top of the screen allow you to manipulate android version, screen size, orientation, themes, and other factors.

Comment: Those existing user interface are not shown.. only new interfaces